# Xcode 13: Bundle name seems unlocalizable

Tags: ios, xcode

I feel unable to make XCode use my localized bundle name (CFBundleDisplayName).

Using XCode 13 with SwiftUI no Info.plist is created by default. All properties from project start are stored in Targets -> Info.

I have created a custom property (App Transport Security Settings) to make XCode create an additional "App-Name"-Info.plist (not Info.plist anymore with SwiftUI). I clicked Localize on the "App-Name"-Info.plist and used English & German. Two localized files are created. To find in their .lproj directories. Setting 'Bundle name' as property in a .plist file did not work.

But creating a InfoPList.strings file and localizing this did not work either. Still the app name remains English.

I set:

CFBundleDisplayName  = "NameDE";

CFBundleName = "bundleDE";

[image]

Not even setting Bundle name in the additionally created "App-Name"-Info.plist does work:

[image]

Will always stay on the name set in Targets -> Build Settings -> Product Name:

[image]

Comment: Bundle identifier is not going to be localizable, it uniquely identifies app. Are you going to have different apps for En/De?

Comment: Bundle name is the one I ment. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bundle Display Name` (NOT `Bundle Name`) to localize the bundle name in `info.plist` like:

`Bundle Display Name = $(PRODUCT_NAME)`

Answer (score 0):

I added a `InfoPlist.strings` file (in the root folder) with:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "English";
"CFBundleName" = "Test";
```

[image: strings file]

[image: has localized display name flag]

This overwrites what I have in Targets -> General. (The display name is "English" instead of "DisplayName")
[image: display name]